# How to call a function (stripslashes) within a PHP string?

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="'.$chapter_title.'"/>
```

I want to add stripslashes to the '.$chapter_title.'

Would I do something like this.

```
<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="stripslashes'.$chapter_title.'"/>
```

How would I do this - not too sure where to put brackets etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is much clearer when you post the whole line. The HTML is part of a string:

```
$some_string = '<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="'.$chapter_title.'"/>';
```

It doesn't really matter that it's HTML for this question, so let's make the example shorter:

```
$some_string = 'abc ' . $chapter_title . ' !!!';
```

That's better. Without HTML's double-quotes, it's much clearer what's going on. The string `$some_string` is the string `'abc '`, concatenated to the PHP variable `$chapter_title`, concatenated to the string `' !!!'`.

In fact, any PHP expression will do, not just an expression. In this case you want to concatenate the value of `stripslashes($chapter_title)` rather than just `$chapter_title` itself, so:

```
$some_string = 'abc ' . stripslashes($chapter_title) . ' !!!';
```

Putting the HTML back in:

```
$some_string = '<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="' . stripslashes($chapter_title) . '"/>';
```

There is plenty of great recommended reading on PHP. I suggest picking up a book with good reviews and going through it. Twice.

Comment: Took the effort to give a full, legitimate explanation. +1

Comment: @nav_nav: The idea is to allow the OP to finally _grok_ what it is that his code is doing. Sometimes with the HTML quotes in the string it can be hard to "see" the PHP concatenation operands until that first epiphany :)

Comment: Many THanks for your excellent response - I am new and thank you - I will get a book to read over the weekend.

Comment: I have just 2 more places that need the same stripslashes. They are a different to above.                                                   <input name="title" value="Untitled" size="36" style="height: 25px"> - I need to stripslashes on the value - and the value in this instance - input name="author" value="'.$_SESSION['uidrealname'].'" size="36" style="height: 25px">

Comment: @Dom: Well, now you know how PHP concatenation with function results works, you can `stripslashes` away 'til your heart's content.

Comment: @dom `value="' . stripslashes($_SESSION['uidrealname']). '"` - Do you see how its the same as the one on Lightness's answer? The only difference is, the variable you want to stripslash...

Comment: I still don;t get it fully - could you help me with just those other 2 values please

Comment: sorry - Thanks for answering - your post wasn't there when I asked last question

Comment: @Dom: You can also use functions within functions, for-instance, you might have a string like '    My name\'s Dom'. With this you want to remove the whitespace before '    My ..' (`trim`) and remove the \ (`stripslashes`). So, you can say `$some_string = trim(stripslashes($chapter_title));`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dom If you still need any help, check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_stripslashes.asp

Comment: is there a way to stop it putting in these slashes on the whole site so I don;t haveto keep doing this?

Comment: Time to go to a chatroom. This is not the place for an extended discussion or iterative help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I really don't understand all the hype about W3Schools. But it was relevant for the OP so I decided to share it.

Comment: @nav_nav: It's generally full of poor and incomplete advice. Prefer [the actual manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php); I don't see why you'd ever want to post a link to something else that pretends to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `$chapter_title` as an argument to stripslashes:

```
<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="'.stripslashes($chapter_title).'"/>
```

Further readings:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_syntax_and_semantics#Functions

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter" value="' . stripslashes($chapter_title) .'"/>
```

You used ' to tell php that the HTML string ends. Than append the value of the function stripslashes, which gets the $chapter_title as input argument. And than append the rest of the HTML string.